# Efficiently return specific rows in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I'm trying to return each item in a row based off places in `Column D`.

At the moment I'm doing this via `df = df.loc[df['D'] == '#specific place']`.

This works fine but if I have 50 different places this code becomes very inefficient. I would have to alter `df = df.loc[df['D'] == '#another specific place']` 50 times. I would do this if the places stayed the same but each dataset contains different places.

Is there a more efficient way to return the rows for each place? I have a separate `df` with each place that I can return to a `list`. Can I use the values in this list to return the functions in

```
import pandas as pd

places = ['Home','Away','Shops']

d = ({
    'C' : ['08:00:00','XX','08:10:00','XX','08:41:42','XX','08:50:00','XX', '09:00:00', 'XX','09:15:00','XX','09:21:00','XX','09:30:00','XX','09:40:00','XX'],
    'D' : ['Home','','Home','','Away','','Shops','','Away','','Shops','','Home','','Away','','Home',''],
    'E' : ['Num:','','Num:','','Num:','','Num:','','Num:', '','Num:','','Num:','','Num:', '','Num:', ''],
    'F' : ['1','','1','','1','','1','','1', '','2','','2','','1', '','2',''],   
    'A' : ['A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A','','A',''],           
    'B' : ['Stop','','Res','','Stop','','Start','','Res','','Stop','','Res','','Start','','Start','']
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#Select desired place
Home = df.loc[df['D'] == 'Home']
Shops = df.loc[df['D'] == 'Shops']
Away = df.loc[df['D'] == 'Away']
```

Intended Output:

```
    A      B         C     D     E  F
0   A   Stop  08:00:00  Home  Num:  1
2   A    Res  08:10:00  Home  Num:  1
12  A    Res  09:21:00  Home  Num:  2
16  A  Start  09:40:00  Home  Num:  2
6   A  Start  08:50:00  Shops  Num:  1
10  A   Stop  09:15:00  Shops  Num:  2
4   A   Stop  08:41:42  Away  Num:  1
8   A    Res  09:00:00  Away  Num:  1
14  A  Start  09:30:00  Away  Num:  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is just a groupby() and then probably a list of excluded/included unique items in column 'D':

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['C'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['C'], errors="coerce").dt.total_seconds()

places = ['Home','Away','Shops']

for d, dfg in df[df['D'].isin(places)].groupby('D'):
    # print out the processing place
    print('group:{}\n{}'.format(d, dfg))
    # do whatever you want on `dfg` and `d`
    # In your example, when d is 'Home', dfg is df.loc[df['D'] == 'Home']
    # below your code, just change `df` to `dfg`
    #Return start-stop times
    Stop = dfg.loc[df['B'] == 'Stop'].reset_index()['C']
    Start = dfg.loc[df['B'] == 'Start'].reset_index()['C']
    Res = dfg.loc[df['B'] == 'Res'].reset_index()['C']

    #return difference
    Start_diff = Start - Stop
    Res_diff = Res - Start
```

Comment: Thanks @jxc. How does this work sorry? Is it `excluded = ['Everything I want', 'Unwanted']`.

Comment: Hi, @PeterJames123: `excluded` is a list of unique values from column-D which you don't want to include in your processing routine(for example when D is EMPTY). `df[ ~df.D.isin(excluded) ]` will filter out those rows. On the other hand, you can also explicitly specify all 50 places for example `included = ['Home', 'Away', 'Everything I want' ......]` and then use:  `df[df.D.isin(included)].groupby('D'):`   (remove `~` which is bitwise invert)

Comment: I've simplified the question @jxc. Your solution didn't return each place. If I had an empty list it only returns one place. Not all

Comment: OK, I just adjusted the code so it will include the list of places you just added. (`print()` line is only for debugging). However if there is no record for a `place` in column-D ('Shops'), it will not show in the result.

Comment: Thanks @jxc. If I wanted to use that df for future work what output code would I use?

Comment: Hi, @PeterJames123. if I understand you right, you should use `dfg` in your routine code which will be pointed to the specific `place`.

Answer (score 0):

you can identify your places by looping through df['B'] and indentify non empty string and saving them in a list for example

```
places = []
for i in df['B']:
    if i!="":places.append(i)
###now you can create a dict to save the differences
diff_result = {}
for i in places:
    Stop = df.loc[df['B'] == i].reset_index()['C']
    Start = df.loc[df['B'] == i].reset_index()['C']
    Res = df.loc[df['B'] == i].reset_index()['C']
    diff_result[i+"_diff"] = Res
```

now you have a dictionary filled with the wanted result

Comment: There's an SyntaxError in line `if i:="Home":places.append(i)`